# AWS amplify datastore wont synchronise with server

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

So I'm trying to get AWS Amplify's datastore library working with a reactJS web app I'm building. I was sending data to and from the api just fine using the graphql mutations manually, and then I tried to set up DataStore by following [this tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js). Everything is working fine in the client with the indexed DB, but I can't get the data to synchronise with the api. I get the following error in the console:

```
 DataStore - Data won't be synchronized. No GraphQL endpoint configured. Did you forget `Amplify.configure(awsconfig)`?
```

I doubled checked, and I'm definitely including my AWS export as so:

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
import awsExports from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsExports);
```

And the content of the generated `./aws-exports.js` is the following:

```
/* eslint-disable */
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-2_xxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "oauth": {}
};


export default awsmobile;
```

I've double checked the credentials for `aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint` and `aws_appsync_apiKey` and they match the values returned from `amplify status` in the cli. I've also run `amplify push` and my Api has a status of `No Change`. When setting up the api I made sure to enable the conflict resolution too, as specified in the tutorial.

Interestingly, I also tried the following when setting up amplify:

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
import {DataStore} from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import awsExports from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsExports);
DataStore.configure(awsExports);
```

This solved the `DataStore - Data won't be synchronised` error, but I got the following errors instead, and the data still isn't being sent to the api.

```
DataStore - subscriptionError Subscribe only available for AWS AppSync endpoint
DataStore - Sync error Subscribe only available for AWS AppSync endpoint
```

Does this mean my API is somehow not configured properly? How Would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 3):

I have been fiddling with the DataStore syncing  for a while in a Angular project. Here is what I think I learned, from my observations or answers posted by others

1. Can't use API key authentication, that does not work. I use `Cognito` user pool and that works
2. Had to enable `Optimistic Concurrency` as conflict resolution
   strategy, but I think it works even with the default `Auto Merge`, not sure exactly when is the first needed
3. All types need an auto-generated id of type "ID!". Without that, you
   get errors when the listeners are setup and syncing does not work
   even for types that have it.
4. Make sure the code is regenerated and pushed, and DataStore stays
   enabled after each schema change (sometimes that setting may reset)

For troubleshooting, enable tracing (`Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'`) and filter in browser's console for messages that contain "err". If any such messages exist, the entire sync does not work. That is how you can tell if you have one of the issues above.

Another trick is to delete the local `amplify-datastore` `IndexDB` in Chrome Dev Tools' Application/Storage. If sync works, it will be re-populated from the DynamoDB table data in the cloud next time you reload your app.

Comment: The tip to enable debug level logging was a life saver - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I imported `DataStore` from `aws-amplify` instead of `@aws-amplify/datastore`. It took me a while to figure it out but all I had to do was change the import statement.

So, try changing your import statement from:

`import { DataStore } from "aws-amplify";`

to:

`import { DataStore } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";`

Comment: I had a similar problem. I found that you must import `Amplify` from `@aws-amplify/core` and **NOT** from `aws-amplify`

The following code example worked well in App.js, at the **BOTTOM** of all your imports:

    `import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
    import { DataStore, Predicates } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
    import { Post, PostStatus } from "./models";
    
    //Use next two lines only if syncing with the cloud
    import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
    Amplify.configure(awsconfig);`

Source: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/examples/q/platform/js

Comment: thanks so much. it was driving me nuts that my datastore would not sync. import Amplify from @aws-amplify/core and NOT from aws-amplify solved it for me. i can't believe that amazon with all the money they have, cannot come up with better documentation! or at least keep it up to date as they make changes!

Answer (score 1):

This must be a problem, coming up with a recent update. About a week ago I successfully used DataStore (v2.2.8) in an expo app. Yesterday, I started a new expo app project and cannot figure out a way to get the DataStore up and running with sync. Did you try an older version of @aws-amplify/datastore?

Comment: Just tried the opposite and updated to the latest version (2.4.0) and it started working. So you're right, it must have been a bug with the version I had. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere from between @aws-amplify/datastore  version 2.9.6 to 2.9.9 they changed the Amplify Configure.  You now need to put your `aws-exports` in `{config: }`   However, I can not get 2.9.9 to load data, so I'm staying on 2.9.8

2.9.8 and before:

```
import awsConfig from "./aws-exports";
import { Amplify} from "@aws-amplify/core";
Amplify.configure(awsConfig);
```

2.9.9:

```
import awsConfig from "./aws-exports";
import { Amplify} from "@aws-amplify/core";
Amplify.configure({ config: { awsConfig } });
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what other people have said. Try removing the `node modules` & `package-lock.json`. Then run `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm i`. This worked for me with just normal `Amplify.configure(config)`

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your application, do this:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import config from "../src/aws-exports.js";

Amplify.configure({
  ...config,
});
```

That should fix it for you.