# DataStore - Data won't be synchronized. No GraphQL endpoint configured. Did you forget `Amplify.configure(awsconfig)`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Please help, i spent 2 days trying simply to use Datastore of amplify. Am building NPM package to wrap an Amplify project backend. Auth works good but datastore not.
Am testing code with ts-node and Jest. It is package so i do not have a framework.

When i call the save function it does not work and throw this warning:

```js
[WARN] 24:08.886 DataStore - Data won't be synchronized. No GraphQL endpoint configured. Did you forget `Amplify.configure(awsconfig)`? {
  config: {
    authProviders: undefined,
    maxRecordsToSync: 10000,
    syncPageSize: 1000
  }
}
```

My api endpoint is 100% correct, also the api-key. The backend works in another project built with react. But in my case (NPM package) it does not work.

The script am trying to run:

```js
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { AccountDetails }  from '@/models';
import { SignUp } from "@/Authentication/SignUp";
import InvalidAccountRequirementsException from "@/Exceptions/InvalidAccountRequirementsException";
import "@/app.config";

/**
 * @name CreateAccount
 * @description:
 *      build the correct pattern to check specific string type.
 *
 * @type function
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * @param hasOwnCompany
 * @param optInMarketingEmail
 * @param tacAgreed
 * @constructor
 * @return {Promise<AccountDetails>}
 */
const CreateAccount = async (
    email: string,
    password: string,
    hasOwnCompany: boolean,
    optInMarketingEmail: boolean,
    tacAgreed: boolean,
): Promise<AccountDetails> => {

    if (!tacAgreed) {
        throw new InvalidAccountRequirementsException('Terms and conditions mus be agreed');
    }

    const user = await SignUp(email, password);

    return await DataStore.save(
        new AccountDetails({
            cognitoSubId: user.userSub,
            email: email,
            optInMarketingEmail: optInMarketingEmail,
            tacAgreed: tacAgreed,
            hasOwnCompany: hasOwnCompany,
        })
    );
}

export default CreateAccount;
```

app.conf.ts

```js
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsExports from '@/aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsExports);
```

package.json

```js
{
    "name": "@financiallease/driver-seat-amplify-api",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "author": "itsupport@financiallease.nl",
    "main": "dist/financiallease.cjs.js",
    "module": "dist/financiallease.es.js",
    "browser": "dist/financiallease.js",
    "license": "ISC",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rollup -c",
        "lint": "eslint --config eslint.config.js '{src,test}/**/*.ts' --no-ignore",
        "autoformat": "eslint --config eslint.config.js '{src,test}/**/*.ts' --no-ignore --fix",
        "test": "jest -c jest.config.ts",
        "coverage": "jest --collectCoverage --coverageDirectory=\"./coverage\" --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --watchAll=false",
        "docs:generate": "typedoc --readme README.md --entryPoints src --entryPointStrategy expand --out docs --theme hierarchy --name \"Driver Seat Amplify Api - docs\" --includeVersion",
        "amplify-modelgen": "node amplify/scripts/amplify-modelgen.js",
        "amplify-push": "node amplify/scripts/amplify-push.js"
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "@financiallease:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/35071033/packages/npm/"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@aws-amplify/core": "^4.5.1",
        "@aws-amplify/datastore": "^3.11.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^3.1.9",
        "aws-amplify": "^4.3.19",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
        "typescript": "^4.6.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
        "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.3",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.1.3",
        "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.1",
        "@types/amplify": "^1.1.25",
        "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.30",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.18.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.18.0",
        "babel-jest": "^28.0.3",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.12.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
        "esm": "^3.2.25",
        "jest": "^27.5.1",
        "jest-junit": "^13.2.0",
        "jsdoc": "^3.6.10",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
        "rollup": "^2.70.1",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
        "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.14.1",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typedoc": "^0.22.15",
        "typedoc-theme-hierarchy": "^1.1.1",
        "ini": "^1.3.5",
        "inquirer": "^6.5.1"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS amplify datastore wont synchronise with server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646190/aws-amplify-datastore-wont-synchronise-with-server)